# ImageResizer Debug "Sequence contains no matching element"

Tags: asp.net, .net, imageresizer

Whenever I try to access "resizer.debug" or "resizer.debug.ashx", I get a "Sequence contains no matching element" error. I am using pre-release 4.0.0. It worked fine in 3.4.3.

I posted this question on the ImageResizer website and I was asked to move it here with a copy of my web.config. So, here I am!

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>





  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="vsproductsConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\acessdb.mdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="leftNavSearchCriteriaGroupIds" value="3,4,1" />
    <add key="productNameSearchCriteriaGroupIds" value="3,4,1" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0">
    </pages>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
    <trust level="Full" />




    <httpModules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
        <add value="default.asp" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <!--<allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="ORIGINAL_URI" />
        <add name="RULE_ID" />
      </allowedServerVariables>-->
      <rules>
        <rule name="Section" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^products/([^/]*)(/*)$" />
          <conditions>
            <add matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="products.aspx?sn={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
          <!--<serverVariables>
            <set name="HEADER_ORIGINAL_URI" value="{REQUEST_URI}" />
          </serverVariables>-->
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>


    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <resizer>

    <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" defaultCommands="autorotate.default=true"/>
    <diagnostics enableFor="localhost" />
    <plugins>
      <!--<add name="PdfRenderer" downloadNativeDependencies="true" />-->
      <add name="PdfiumRenderer" downloadNativeDependencies="true"/>
    </plugins>
  </resizer>
</configuration>
```

Also, here is the text from the error page...

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Sequence contains no matching element
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]
>      System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +276
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DiagnosticPageHandler.GenerateOutput(HttpContext context, Config c) +2730
>      ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DiagnosticPageHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +138
>      System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +188
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.79.0

Answer (score 0):

We've fixed this bug in [4.0.0.901](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/imazen/resizer/build/4.0.0.901) [zip](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/imazen/resizer/build/4.0.0.901/job/pe1dw01ymmf5ps28/artifacts). It occurs when you don't have any of the standard plugins installed, like DiskCache.

Check our [nuget feed](http://imageresizing.net/download) for the latest versions of the packages.

Comment: https://www.myget.org/F/imazen-nightlies/ does not work in my NuGet Package Manager.

Comment: I added the link to my NuGet repositories; but searching it returns no results. Honestly, I probably just don't know how to use it.